# Name of the character who introduces the viewer to the larger story?

Tags: character, terminology

In many films, TV shows, and books, there exists a character who begins the story as a "normal" person, and then gets caught up in some larger, ongoing conflict. This person becomes the "new guy" on a team of people already familiar with the conflict. This creates a vehicle for the team members to teach the new character, and therefore the viewer, the important points of the story already in progress.

**What is the name for this type of character?**

The clearest example I can think of is Ellen Page's character in *Inception*. Sometimes this charcater is also the main character, like Luke Skywalker, Harry Potter, and Neo, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NaiveNewcomer?from=Main.TheNewGuy + https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AudienceSurrogate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trope is called "the new guy" https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NaiveNewcomer?from=Main.TheNewGuy

If troubles turn the character into a protagonist, you might invoke the reluctant hero instead https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IJustWantToBeNormal?from=Main.Reluctanthero

Comment: Exactly what I was picturing. TV Tropes is great, but nearly impossible to guess the name of the concept you're looking for, and too many tropes to read them all.